# Does the Razor View Engine in ASP.NET support structs or custom classes?

Tags: razor

It appears that the Razor view engine supports `Dictionary<>`, `List<>`, and other collections.  Does Razor support structs or custom classes such as below?  If so what is the approach to use them?

```
struct gc {
    public string code;
    public string definition;
};

public class gc2 {
    public string code;
    public string definition;
};
```

The statements above are throwing compilation errors. (i.e. `Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected`)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a work around.

By declaring an empty JSON object string - you can decode the string in Razor.  By default, this creates the object which can then be used.

It looks kind of like this:

```
var word = "{\"code\" : [],\"font\" : []}";
var p = Json.Decode(word);
```

Now, p somewhat has the structure of the object needed.

However - if you try to fill the object - it becomes outside the bounds of the array.